# XSLT 2.0 to 1.0

Tags: xslt

Lots of help here to convert XSLT 1.0 to 2.0, but I need to go the other way!

OK, I have an XSL file working in XSLT 2.0: I need to convert this file to XSLT 1.0. Right now, I know the transformation is getting hung up on "result-document" but I'm not sure how to fix this. And, I'm not sure if my other info will translate to 1.0: will my value-of select= statements still work? help! (thanks)!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:result-document href="output.xml" method="xml">
        <playlist>
            <xsl:for-each select="//dict[preceding-sibling::*[1]='Tracks']/dict">
                <Track>
                    <Artist>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Artist']"/>
                    </Artist>
                    <Album>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Album']"/>
                    </Album>
                    <Songname>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Name']"/>
                    </Songname>
                    <TrackID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Track ID']"/>
                    </TrackID>
                    <TagID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Tag ID']"/>
                    </TagID>
                </Track>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="//dict[preceding-sibling::*[1]='Upload Information']">
                <Description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Playlist Description']"/>
                </Description>
                <Title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Playlist Title']"/>
                </Title>
                <Username>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Username']"/>
                </Username>
                <Token>
                    <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Token']"/>
                </Token>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </playlist>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well considering that `result-document` is new in XSLT 2.0 and that XSLT 1.0 without processor specific extension does not allow creating of multiple result documents at all it is in general not possible to translate stylesheets making use of `result-document` to XSLT 1.0.

However in your snippet the `result-document` instruction is inside the template matching the single `/` document node so you could simply remove it and use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
        <playlist>
            <xsl:for-each select="//dict[preceding-sibling::*[1]='Tracks']/dict">
                <Track>
                    <Artist>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Artist']"/>
                    </Artist>
                    <Album>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Album']"/>
                    </Album>
                    <Songname>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Name']"/>
                    </Songname>
                    <TrackID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Track ID']"/>
                    </TrackID>
                    <TagID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Tag ID']"/>
                    </TagID>
                </Track>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="//dict[preceding-sibling::*[1]='Upload Information']">
                <Description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Playlist Description']"/>
                </Description>
                <Title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Playlist Title']"/>
                </Title>
                <Username>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Username']"/>
                </Username>
                <Token>
                    <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Token']"/>
                </Token>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </playlist>

</xsl:template>
```

Of course you would then need to ensure you run your XSLT processor with the right arguments to write its result to `output.xml`.

As for `value-of`, check whether any of the used expressions selects multiple nodes in your input XML documents. But you only need to check if the stylesheet had once `version="2.0"` and was run that way with an XSLT 2.0 processor. Your posted snippet has `version="1.0"`, that way even an XSLT 2.0 processor would run it in backwards compatible mode where `value-of` semantics (output string value of first selected node) is used.

So the value-of only need adaption if with version="2.0" they output multiple values and you want to preserve that with version="1.0". You need to use `for-each` then e.g. by replacing

```
                    <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Token']"/>
```

with

```
  <xsl:for-each select="child::*[preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Token']">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: thanks: "Of course you would then need to ensure you run your XSLT processor with the right arguments to write its result to output.xml." I want to apply the XML-XSLT-to-XML translation to run via PHP 5.3 on a server. I.e. I upload the original XML and XSLT and get an XML output file output to download.  How would I change my xsl:result-document statement?

Comment: Consider to ask a new question tagged as PHP where you clearly explain where the XML input comes from and where the XSLT result is supposed to be written to (file on the server, response to browser?). As I have shown, the `xsl:result-document` instruction simply needs to be removed. If you run XSLT with PHP on the server, then someone else needs to help you using the PHP APIs.

Comment: Got it working, thanks for your help. I actually had a problem in that the stylesheet tag wasn't closed.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code  with xslt-1.0 would be the `<xsl:result-document href="output.xml" method="xml">`. This is not supported for xslt-1.0

One possible solution could be to remove this (xsl:result-document) and redirect the "stdout" output to a file. This depends  on the tools you are using.

Also some xlst processor support some extensions. For example wiht xsltproc you can replace 
xsl:result-document with xsl:document.